# Dropdown menu dissapears on click

Tags: html, css

I have tried everything but it still dissapears on click. This is the video I followed btw https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAIVbLrAb_U&t=21s&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified.

CSS

```
:root {
        --bar-width: 60px;
        --bar-height: 8px;
        --hamburger-gap: 6px;
        --foreground: #333;
        --background: white;
        --hamburger-margin: 125px;
        --animation-timing: 200ms ease-in-out;
        --hamburger-height: calc(var(--bar-height)*3+var(--hamburger-gap)*2)
    }

    .hamburger-menu {
        --x-width: calc(var(--hamburger-height)*1.41421356237);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: var(--hamburger-gap);
        width: max-content;
        position: absolute;
        top: var(--hamburger-margin);
        left: var(--hamburger-margin);
        z-index: 999;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .hamburger-menu::before,
    .hamburger-menu::after,
    .hamburger-menu input {
        content: "";
        width: var(--bar-width);
        height: var(--bar-height);
        background-color: var(--foreground);
        border-radius: 999px;
        transform-origin: left center;
        transition: opacity var(--animation-timing), width var(--animation-timing);
    }

    .hamburger-menu input {
        appearance: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        outline: none;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    .hamburger-menu:has(input:checked)::before {
        rotate: 45deg;
        width: var(--x-width);
        translate: 0 calc(var(--bar-height)/-2);
    }

    .hamburger-menu:has(input:checked)::after {
        rotate: -45deg;
        width: var(--x-width);
        translate: 0 calc(var(--bar-height)/2);
    }

    .hamburger-menu input:checked {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="nav-items">
                <label class="hamburger-menu">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set width of `hamburger-menu` 's input as 1.

code like:

```
    .hamburger-menu input:checked {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
    }
```

=>

```
    .hamburger-menu input:checked {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 1;
    }
```